# Java Decompiler - Shows different package structure

Tags: java, eclipse, package, decompiler

I tried to view a class file using Gel and i tried opening the same file in eclipse using jad eclipse it has got compiled to a different package i.e.., shows a different package structure.

My question here is, does the package gets changed when we use different De-compiler's.

example:-

Gel :- package directoryutility;

eclipse:- package multidirutility;

[image: eclipse decompiled]

[image: Gel Decompiled]

Comment: No it doesn't. Can you provide more information please? Ideally wiht screenshots.

Comment: Hope, now it is more informative. I just copied the class file viewed using GEL to eclipse and opened

Comment: That's weird. Can you post the jar please?

Comment: net.sf.jadclipse_3.3.0.jar - this is the eclipse jar file that I am using.

Comment: No, I mean can you post the jar you are trying to decompile?

Comment: Hi, that is just a class file. Do you want me to post class file ?

Comment: Yes. Or if you're trying to decompile a jar, post that